# Tracking change of variable in Python

Tags: python, descriptor

I would like to create a data structure containing several settings, these settings will be used to calculate register values of a hardware device. To avoid reconfiguring all settings of the hardware device, I would like to have each variable inside of the data structure remember if it has been changed or not. Then later I would call upon all variables to see which ones are changed to then only write to the connected registers.
I can create a class that remembers if any change has occurred to it's internally stored value, I am however experiencing difficulties with returning and resetting the `has_changed` variable. This due to the overloading of the `__get__` function prohibiting the usage of other functions inside of the class.

In the simplified example I have made a class called `Table` (which should contain variables such as: `height`, `width`, `length`, ...) The current implementation has the class `TrackedValidatedInteger` which checks if the change is valid.
I would like the variable property `has_changed` to be obtainable and resettable from inside of the class `Table`.

```
class TrackedValidatedInteger():
    def __init__(self, min_value=None, max_value=None):
        self.min_value = min_value
        self.max_value = max_value
        self.has_changed = False
        self.value = None
        
    def __get__(self, obj, objecttype=None):
        return self.value
    
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if self.validate_set(value):
            self.value = value
            self.has_changed = True
            return 1
        return 0

    def get_has_changed(self):
        return self.has_changed
    
    def reset_has_changed(self):
        self.has_changed = False
        
    def validate_set(self, value):
        if self.min_value:
            if self.min_value > value:
                print("Value should be between " + str(self.min_value) + " and " + str(self.max_value))
                return 0
        if self.max_value:
            if self.max_value < value:
                print("Value should be between " + str(self.min_value) + " and " + str(self.max_value))
                return 0
        return 1

class Table():
    length = TrackedValidatedInteger(min_value=0, max_value=3)
    height = TrackedValidatedInteger(min_value=0, max_value=6)
    width = TrackedValidatedInteger(min_value=0, max_value=7)
    
    def __init__(self, length=0, height=0, width=0):
        self.length = length
        self.height = height
        self.width = width 

    def reset_has_changed_1(self):
        self.length.has_changed = False
        self.height.has_changed = False
        self.width.has_changed = False
        
    def reset_has_changed_2(self):
        self.length.reset_has_changed()
        self.height.reset_has_changed()
        self.width.reset_has_changed()


p = Table()
p.length = 3 # will set the variable
p.length = 9 # will not set the variable

# p.length.get_has_changed() # This does not work as the p.length will call __get__ resulting in an integer which does not have get_has_changed()
# p.reset_has_changed_1() # This does not work for the same reason
# p.reset_has_changed_2() # This does not work for the same reason
```

The problem I find is that the `__get__` function gets automatically called whenever I try to access any other part of the `TrackedValidatedInteger` class. Can I access the other variables and functions in any other way? If there are any suggestions on how achieve the same result in another way, I would be glad to hear it. I would personally like to keep the simple setting of the variables (`p.length = 3`), if not possible this can be changed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the idea of doing this from a descriptor. You can take advantage of the fact that a descriptor can know the name of the attribute to which it is bound via the [`__set_name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#customized-names) method, and use that to maintain attributes on the target object:

```py
class TrackedValidatedInteger:
    def __init__(self, min_value=None, max_value=None):
        self.min_value = min_value
        self.max_value = max_value
        self.has_changed = False
        self.value = None

    def __set_name__(self, obj, name):
        self.name = name
        setattr(obj, f"{self.name}_changed", False)

    def __get__(self, obj, objecttype=None):
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if (self.min_value is not None and value < self.min_value) or (
            self.max_value is not None and value > self.max_value
        ):
            raise ValueError(
                f"{value} must be >= {self.min_value} and <= {self.max_value}"
            )
        self.value = value
        setattr(obj, f"{self.name}_changed", True)
```

Given the above implementation, we can create a class `Example` like this:

```py
class Example:
    v1 = TrackedValidatedInteger()
    v2 = TrackedValidatedInteger()
```

And then observe the following behavior:

```py
>>> e = Example()
>>> e.v1_changed
False
>>> e.v1 = 42
>>> e.v1_changed
True
>>> e.v2_changed
False
>>> e.v2 = 0
>>> e.v2_changed
True
```

Instead of maintaining a per-attribute `<name>_changed` variable, you could instead maintain a `set` of changed attributes:

```py
class TrackedValidatedInteger:
    def __init__(self, min_value=None, max_value=None):
        self.min_value = min_value
        self.max_value = max_value
        self.has_changed = False
        self.value = None

    def __set_name__(self, obj, name):
        self.name = name
        if not hasattr(obj, "_changed_attributes"):
            setattr(obj, "_changed_attributes", set())

    def __get__(self, obj, objecttype=None):
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        if (self.min_value is not None and value < self.min_value) or (
            self.max_value is not None and value > self.max_value
        ):
            raise ValueError(
                f"{value} must be >= {self.min_value} and <= {self.max_value}"
            )
        self.value = value
        obj._changed_attributes.add(self.name)
```

In that case, we get:

```py
>>> e = Example()
>>> e._changed_attributes
set()
>>> e.v1 = 1
>>> e._changed_attributes
{'v1'}
>>> e.v2 = 1
>>> e._changed_attributes
{'v1', 'v2'}
```

This is nice because you can iterate over `e._changed_attributes` if you need to record all your changed values.

Answer (score 0):

I'd lift the validation and change tracking logic up to the Table, like so:

```
class Table:
    _fields = {}

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._data = {}
        self._changed = set()
        for name, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, name, value)
        self._changed.clear()  # do not consider the initial values as changed

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<{self.__class__.__name__} {self._data}>"

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self._data[item]

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        rules = self._fields.get(key)
        if rules is not None:  # existing field
            if "min_value" in rules and value < rules["min_value"]:
                raise ValueError(f'{key} should be greater than {rules["min_value"]}')
            if "max_value" in rules and value > rules["max_value"]:
                raise ValueError(f'{key} should be less than {rules["max_value"]}')
            self._data[key] = value
            self._changed.add(key)
            return
        if not key.startswith("_"):
            raise AttributeError(f"Cannot set attribute {key}")
        super().__setattr__(key, value)

    def reset_has_changed(self):
        self._changed.clear()

    @property
    def changed(self):
        return tuple(self._changed)


class HardwareTable(Table):
    _fields = {
        "reg1": {"min_value": 0, "max_value": 100},
        "reg2": {"min_value": 0, "max_value": 100},
    }


p = HardwareTable(reg1=30)
print(f"{p=} / {p.changed=}")
p.reg2 = 13
print(f"{p=} / {p.changed=}")
```

This prints out

```
p=<HardwareTable {'reg1': 30}> / p.changed=()
p=<HardwareTable {'reg1': 30, 'reg2': 13}> / p.changed=('reg2',)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues to adress:

- First, instances of `TrackedValidatedInteger` are coupled to `Table`, not to its instances,
  so you should not store `value` on `TrackedValidatedInteger` instances. (Try creating two `Table` instances,
  setting one of these properties on the one, and seeing it reflected on the other instance.)
- If validation fails, you should raise an exception, not print a value and continue on.
- If `min_value` or `max_value` is `0`, you don't do the validation. Use `if self.min_value is not None` instead.
- If one of them is `None`, you print messages like `Value should be between None and 7`

```
class TrackedValidatedInteger:
    def __init__(self, min_value=None, max_value=None):
        self.min_value = min_value
        self.max_value = max_value
        
    def __get__(self, obj, objecttype=None):
        return getattr(obj, self.private_name)
    
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        self.validate(value)
        obj.has_changed.add(self.public_name)
        setattr(obj, self.private_name, value)

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.public_name = name
        self.private_name = '_' + name

    def validate(self, value):
        if (self.min_value is not None and value < self.min_value or
            self.max_value is not None and value > self.max_value):
            if self.min_value is None:
                comparison = f'at most {self.max_value}'
            elif self.max_value is None:
                comparison = f'at least {self.min_value}'
            else:
                comparison = f'between {self.min_value} and {self.max_value}'
            raise ValueError(f'{self.public_name} should be {comparison}')

class Table():
    length = TrackedValidatedInteger(min_value=0, max_value=3)
    height = TrackedValidatedInteger(min_value=0, max_value=6)
    width = TrackedValidatedInteger(min_value=0, max_value=7)
    
    def __init__(self, length=0, height=0, width=0):
        # this needs to happen first:
        self.reset_has_changed()
        self.length = length
        self.height = height
        self.width = width 

    def reset_has_changed(self):
        self.has_changed = set()

p = Table()
p.length = 3 # will set the variable
try:
    p.length = 9 # will not set the variable
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)

print('length' in p.has_changed)
```